# Mobile Detection and cURL redirect giving 404

Tags: php, curl, mobile

So I have a desktop (www.example.com/friends.php) and separate mobile site (m.example.com/friends.php). Not all pages on the desktop site exist on the mobile site.

**The Goal:** I am detecting a mobile device, then if it proves true, I want to capture the desktop URL after the .com (friends.php), and substitute the mobile domain "m.example.com + $pagename". I then want to detect if the page exists on the mobile domain via cURL (see below). If it exists, I want it to redirect to the corresponding mobile page, if it doesn't exists (returns 404), it should redirect to the base mobile domain.

I currently have the function set to alert if a mobile page is found or not based on the 404.

**The issue:** when I testa page I know does not exist, it alerts "mobile page found" always, and then will redirect to the mobile site 404 page. What am I missing here? I've stared at this for hours.

**The Code:**

```
function isMobile() {
return preg_match("/(android|avantgo|blackberry|bolt|boost|cricket|docomo|fone|hiptop|mini|mobi|palm|phone|pie|tablet|up\.browser|up\.link|webos|wos)/i", $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]);}

if(isMobile()){

    function curPageName() {
         return substr($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"],strrpos($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"],"/")+1);
        }

    $pagename = curPageName();      

    $mobileurl = 'http://m.example.com/' + $pagename;
    $curl = curl_init($mobileurl);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);

    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    if ($result !== false) {
        $statusCode = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);  
        if ($statusCode == 404) {
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('mobile url not found');</script>";
            header("Location: http://m.example.com/");
        } else {
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('mobile url found');</script>";
            header("Location:" + $mobileurl);}
    } else {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('mobile url not found');</script>";
        header("Location: http://m.example.com/");
    }

} else {
return false;
```

}

Comment: you should use an .htaccess file and redirect to the homepage when a file doesn't exist ... what you are doing will create an unnecessary load on your server.  Also ... responsive site design its a great solution!

Comment: also your problem with your script is a simple one, you can't output anything before you output a header so you need to remove your echo statements!

Comment: @cmorrissey I know. Unfortunately, I am at a company that is behind the times. I'm working on it ;)

Comment: @cmorrissey I removed my echos, but it's still functioning the same. I have a 404 document defined in my htaccess file, would that be the reason it's not redirecting?